# Abort thread that is created locally in a method

Tags: c#, multithreading

The method below creates and starts a new thread for every client that is connected to TCP listener.

```
void StartClientCommuncationThread(TcpClient Client)
{
    Thread TcpClientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientCommTask));
    TcpClientThread.Start(Client);
}
```

I want to abort all threads when I pressed a button but I don't know how many threads were created and I could not reach the thread outside the method.

How can I abort the threads when I pressed a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually want to do an abort and not just end the thread, is there any reason you can't store the thread references in a collection and then call abort() on everyone?

The comments below are right. It would be better if you listened on a cancellation token to end a thread. However, sometimes you don't control certain threads, lets say something is unresponsive within the thread code because of a 3rd party library.  This is a good time to call abort. Keep in mind that nothing will be cleaned up properly, your finally blocks may not execute, handles that need to be disposed of won't be disposed, etc.  It's a pretty dirty job to call abort.

If you have access to the code running in the thread you should listen for cancellation tokens, or even just a shared (volatile) boolean value indicating that its time to bail out.  If the thread has a long `Thread.Sleep()` in it then you should replace that with a mutex that you can pulse to wake the thread up and tell it to gracefully exit.

With reference to the `IsBackground` property on a thread. MSDN says

> Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating.

So if you need to terminate the thread while your app is running setting this property won't do anything.

Here is an example illustrating the point

```
public class DisposeTest : IDisposable
{
    public void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
        }

        Dispose();

    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("disposing");
    }
}

public class TestDriver
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var diposeTest = new DisposeTest();

        var thread = new Thread(diposeTest.Run)
                            {
                                IsBackground = true
                            };
        thread.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

In this app dispose never gets hit, even though the application didn't hang and exited without error.  This is a bad idea because you can leave sockets open, files unclosed, sql queries unfinished, all sorts of stuff.

There are many ways to end a thread, just be mindful of how you end it because doing so with abort could cause side effects if you aren't careful.

Comment: No! Is that possible? If yes, i can do that.

Comment: Sure it is. Just store each thread object in a List<Thread> and iterate over them and call abort.

Comment: [How To Stop a Thread in .NET (and Why Thread.Abort is Evil)](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation)

Comment: I agree, but he asked for how to abort a thread.  It'd be better if they all listened for a cancellation token or something else, but sometimes abort is appropriate depending on situation. There are many ways to end a thread, but it all depends on what you are doing and what is acceptable or not.  The link you posted talks about why thread.abort is bad because it raises exceptions asynchornously. If you don't really care where the exception is, don't need anything to be disposed of, and don't want to track the exception then there's no reason to not consider this if this is what you need.

Comment: The only time I can think that you'd want to do this is during app exit, in which case setting the Thread property `IsBackground` to `true` will kill all threads when the app closes.

Comment: I updated my response to include these comments. Thanks spender.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is ensure that all your threads are set with **IsBackground = true** before getting started and then on the click of the button you can close the form from where all threads were spawn. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457093.aspx[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457093.aspx)

Comment: From MSDN "Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating." Just because you set it background doesn't mean its not running. This only is appropriate if you don't care about cleanup when the app ends. This doesn't handle cleanup of threads running while your application is running.

Comment: "A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread. Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads are stopped and do not complete." When the applications end, a background thread get immediately terminated compared to a foreground one. Probably it is not relevant because it implies that the app end but it is a way to ensure everything get closed.

Comment: This is true, but this is still an ungraceful exit.